# A delay with jQuery load script of mine

Tags: jquery, html, get, delay

My code has a delay in loading a file. I have to click `<a href="#string" id="hash"></a>`
twice to make it show the .txt file.

The code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#hash").click(function(){
      var loc = $(window)[0].location;
      var getUrlString = $(loc).prop('hash').substr(1);
      $("p").load(getUrlString + '.txt');
    });
  });
</script>

<body>
  <p>This is a placeholder for your content</p>
  <a id="hash" href="#login">Login</button><br />
  <a id="hash" href="#register">Register</button><br />
  <a id="hash" href="#recovery">Recovery</button> 
</body>
```

For example if i click login the first time the page has loaded - it wont show anything.
If i click Register after clicking Login - it will show Login.
If i click Recovery after clicking Register - it will show Register, but if i click Recovery again it will finally show Recovery.

Sorry for my bad english, or if it's hard to understad what's my problem. I'm still learning jQuery, and i find it easier to learn if i try/fail myself, and then find out what's the problem. By just reading tutorials it's not the same :)

Thanks.

Comment: First of all change the 'id'.You can't call the same ID. Use class!

Comment: You don't use `id`'s like that; they need to be unique, ie, not more than one instance of the same `id` for *any* element in the whole document. So `<a id="hash"` should be changed to `<a class="loader"` and `$('a#hash')` to `$('a.loader')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the `ID` should never be repeated within your page. If you need to group elements by an identifier, use a class.

Secondly the problem with the method you have now is that it will read the URL of the window BEFORE it changes to reflect the new URL in the `a` which was clicked. This is why you're seeing the content from the click before appearing. If you need to get the hash value of the URL, it is much easier and simpler to get it from the `href` attribute of the link which was clicked.

With that in mind, try this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.hash").click(function() {
            var textfileName = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
            $("p").load(textfileName + '.txt');
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
    <p>This is a placeholder for your content</p>
    <a class="hash" href="#login">Login</button><br />
    <a class="hash" href="#register">Register</button><br />
    <a class="hash" href="#recovery">Recovery</button> 
</body>
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5RtaR/)

Comment: They will only include forms for login, register, account recoverys and such. Forms only.

And also thank you for the information, i didn't know that before :)

Comment: Hm, with this script, it doesn't load the txt file!

Answer (score 1):

HTML elements must have unique IDs.  You should be using a class and class selector rather than an ID for this.  You also are not closing your anchor tags (you've closed a non-existent `button` instead).  Lastly, you'll want to prevent the default action in the click handler to prevent the link from actually being taken.  If there are no other handlers that need to fire, you can simply return false.  Otherwise, you'll want to use the event object passed to the callback function, `e`, and use `e.preventDefault();`.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.hash").click(function(e){
      var loc = $(window)[0].location;
      var getUrlString = $(loc).prop('hash').substr(1);
      $("p").load(getUrlString + '.txt');
      // you probably want an .htm file, though it will likely work
      // with HTML in a .txt file; browsers are forgiving
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>

<body>
  <p>This is a placeholder for your content</p>
  <a class="hash" href="#login">Login</a><br />
  <a class="hash" href="#register">Register</a><br />
  <a class="hash" href="#recovery">Recovery</a> 
</body>
```

I also have no idea why you're trying to load a *text* file into the paragraph.  Typically, you'd want to load up either an *HTML* file or the results of executing some script.

Comment: This was made for me to test the script, a paragraph was the easiest thing that came up to my mind. :)
But thank you!

Comment: @Kristjan - web servers don't always serve up every kind of file (MIME type).  I suspect you're doing this locally using the file system, but you want to be careful to develop good habits.  A file of *HTML* should be served up with a `.htm` or `.html` extension, even if there is no mark up in it.  Otherwise you might need to double check your web server settings to see if `.txt` files are allowed.